# All life and All lives

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between them?

> Earth was created for ***all lives***, not just human life.
>
> Earth was created for ***all life***, not just human life.

I found the second on http://thriveglobal.com/stories/animal-compassion But the first sentence I made up.

Comment: If you want to maintain a parallel structure, it should be *human* ***lives*** in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"All lives" in this case refers the every life of every creature. The perspective is on the individual.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/life) defines it as:

> A living individual; the fact of a particular individual being alive.

"All life" refers to a macro level. Life as opposed to non-life, e.g. water, rocks, etc.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/life) defines it as:

> Lifeforms, generally or collectively.

Comment: Dictionary link? Mass noun vs countable?

Comment: To me the contrast is between individual living things and *kinds* of life.